# Performing a count on an SQL expression

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have the  current query:

```
SELECT count(*) as number_of_items,
    if(first_name <> "", 1, 0)
    + if(last_name <> "", 1, 0)
    + if(current_avatar is not null, 1, 0)
    + if(username <> "" 
        AND email <> "" 
        AND gender <> "" 
        AND date_of_birth <> "" ,1,0) AS completeness 
FROM `user` HAVING (completeness = '4')
```

But this doesn't work as intended. It seems to count them all having completeness being 2. If I remove the count and having clauses, it do see all the different completeness counts (from 1 to 4). Is there a way to count individual completeness counts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `group by completeness` for this to work:

```
SELECT count(*) as number_of_items,
    if(first_name <> "", 1, 0)
    + if(last_name <> "", 1, 0)
    + if(current_avatar is not null, 1, 0)
    + if(username <> "" 
        AND email <> "" 
        AND gender <> "" 
        AND date_of_birth <> "" ,1,0) AS completeness 
FROM `user`
GROUP BY completeness
HAVING (completeness = '4')
```

Comment: You should provide full modified query code (to get some up votes! lol)

Comment: Ah yes. That does solve it. Thought that by using count, you are implicitly grouping, but that assumption is apparently wrong.

Comment: @ikke Most varieties of SQL other than Mysql would have rejected your original query as incorrect syntax. You may find it beneficial to write more standard SQL